# How to verify that two images are exactly identical?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am writing an opencv program where I track position of an object by use of a usb camera. To make sure I get as high frame rate as possible with the camera I am using I made a threaded process that read the images from the camera. The image processing is done in another loop which also writes the object position to the file.

Now I want a way to avoid processing the same frame multiple times. So I thought I could compare the image just processed with that available from the the video stream thread.

First I tried to use if frame1 == frame2, but got error message that "the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()." 
After some googling I found cv2.compare and the flag CMP_EQ. Made a sample code, and made it work in some way. However, my question is. How could this be done in an easier or better way?

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('image1', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('image2', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

frame1 = cv2.imread("sample1.png")
frame2 = frame1
frame3 = cv2.imread("sample2.png")

compare1 = cv2.compare(frame1,frame2,0)
compare2 = cv2.compare(frame1,frame3,0)

cv2.imshow('image1', compare1)
cv2.imshow('image2', compare2)

if compare1.all():
    print "equal"
else:
    print "not equal"

if compare2.all():
    print "equal"
else:
    print "not equal"

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you considered hashing the images and comparing ?

Comment: How can I hash an image?

Comment: Using hashlib?.. `hashlib.md5(open(full_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about giving your Images an index?

Pseudocode:

```
class Frame
{
   cvImage img;
   uint    idx;
}
```

Than simply check if the current index is greater than the last one you processed. 
It is simple and definitely faster than any image processing based approach.

Comment: That is the way to go. How would you do it in Python? Is there an opencv function for this, or should I just make a code to increase an index for every frame the stream returns?

Comment: I would do it in Python like in the Example. Make a class that contains an index and the image, this way you can later add more information for Example if you capture from two cameras you can add an source identifier. Then just count the images in your capture loop. I think OpenCV has nothing build in.

Comment: I forgot to write that I am quite new to programming, so I must admit I don't understand the example you provided, can you explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: All you need to know is the concept of classes: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner's_Python_Tutorial/Classes

Comment: Hmm, I have the basic understanding of a class, but I don't understand your pseudocode and how you mean it could be implemented and used. I like your idea, and I implemented something that now works by counting each frame, and avoid the main loop from processing if the counter value has not increased. However I think your solution is way more elegant if I was able to understand it...

Comment: Sorry, I had no internet access over the weekend. Glad that you got it working!

Answer (score 43):

```
open("image1.jpg","rb").read() == open("image2.jpg","rb").read()
```

should tell you if they are exactly the same ...

Comment: I think this works only when the PNG files are written using the same compression level, otherwise .read() will report they are different.

Comment: because they are not identical ... the compression level effects the pixels ... at least as i understand it... I might be wrong ...

Answer (score 10):

I was doing something close to what you are doing; I was trying to get the difference. I used the subtract function. It may help you.

**UPDATE:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
a = cv2.imread("sample1.png")
b = cv2.imread("sample2.png")
difference = cv2.subtract(a, b)    
result = not np.any(difference)
if result is True:
    print "Pictures are the same"
else:
    cv2.imwrite("ed.jpg", difference )
    print "Pictures are different, the difference is stored as ed.jpg"
```

Comment: That will result to an array with the difference for each pixel between `a` and `b`. In order to find out whether the two images are the same, you'd then have to compare `difference` to an array of the same size full of zeros, which is the same problem as comparing `a` and `b`.

Comment: Correct and Thank you, I should have added the following
res = not np.any(difference)
this would result true if they are the same. I will update the code I posted.

Comment: A very simple solution would be `np.all(a == b)`, which is very close to what the OP was doing. However, Mailerdaimon's approach of not even comparing the images is more appropriate here.

Comment: Independent of the OP's context, this is very helpful for answering the short question posed by the topic.  One thing to note, though, is that while this is checking for literal equality, it does not check for semantic equality in images containing transparency (e.g. it doesn't provide a way to say that two pixels' render values are equal if their alphas are 0; if the RGB data is not equal, this method won't catch that the alpha channel overrides the RGB data's relevance)

Comment: that is a wrong answer. if sample1.png is all black (pixels are zero), no matter what sample2.png image is, cv2.subtract(a, b) would give an array that is all zero. it would tell that the images are equal while they are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the size of two image files as the first level of check for reduced computational complexity. With compression, it is highly unlikely for two different image files to have the same size to the accuracy of the number of bytes. With equal file size, you can then compare the image contents.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original = cv2.imread("rpi1.jpg")
duplicate = cv2.imread("rpi2.jpg")

if original.shape == duplicate.shape:
    print("The images have same size and channels")
    difference = cv2.subtract(original, duplicate)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

    if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and 
cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
        print("The images are completely Equal")

else:
    print("images are different")
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation for your answer?